# LinkedIn - embed images as media on user profiles using OEmbed

Tags: linkedin-api, oembed

I am attempting to embed OEmbed "photo" types, which are pulled from my website, on LinkedIn profiles as media for experience entries. I also use the LinkedIn API to implement Login with LinkedIn. I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

Previously I was using Embed.ly, service which, from what I understand, LinkedIn use to display media elegantly throughout the site. Up to very recently, adding a link to my website as media to an experience entry on a profile triggered an Embed.ly embed, but now the link is not processed at all, instead throwing an error message such as the one in this image:
[image]

Can you help me? Is there a new procedure I can implement so that my links will result in embeds on profiles?

Thanks for your help.

PS the link I am testing is the following: https://www.gradba.se/v/ac/?d=1mgteqam2a4EZDvyvn7dc7e0dZZZTr18&iss=York%20St%20John%20University